# Function to create new df by counting occurrences by distinct values from several columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

**Objective:**

I would like to write a function that allows me to pass several columns in my `args` and then count the # of occurrences for each distinct value and ultimately paste the result in a new `DataFrame`.

For example, following the schema below, I would like to count how many times the grades of 1,2,3,4,5 from column a,b,c occured:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| a | b | c | d | e |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 5 | 5 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 5 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

**Code:**

I tried the following but it doesnt work

```
 new_df['a_count'] = df.groupby('a').size()
 new_df['b_count'] = df.groupby('b').size()
 new_df['c_count'] = df.groupby('c').size()
```

How can I get this to work as one single function that allows the user to pass multiple columns all at once?

Comment: Do you want to have counts on each column or combined?

Comment: @Chris on seperate columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try is using `pd.Series.value_counts()`:

```
# Mock df
df = pd.DataFrame({key:np.random.randint(1, 6, 5) for key in "abcde"})
   a  b  c  d  e
0  5  5  2  4  5
1  1  1  2  3  4
2  1  1  1  4  4
3  2  1  1  1  4
4  5  2  4  5  3

cols = ["a", "b", "c"]
new_df = pd.concat([df[c].value_counts() for c in cols], 1).fillna(0).astype(int)
print(new_df)
   a  b  c
1  2  3  2
2  1  1  2
4  0  0  1
5  2  1  0
```